# What is the standard practice regarding storing JWT in Angular app?

Tags: angular, jwt

I am taking an assessment as part of a job application. The task is to create an angular app which will fetch data from the specified api using the given JWT token.

I have not used JWT token before, so I am not sure what are the best way to handle these tokens in Angular app. If it makes any difference, I am using Angular 6.

Currently, I am just hard coding it in my service and sending it in the header as a part of the request. Like below:  I feel there has to be some kind of best practice on how to handle this. Could someone share how its done?

```
export class MyService {

  private readonly _apiPath = `https://my.address.com/api/products`;

  private readonly _headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'authorization': `Bearer andVeryLongJWTTokenHere`});

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
      return this.http.get<Product[]>(`${this._apiPath}`, { headers: this._headers });
  }

}
```

Comment: I've always used LocalStorage but I wouldn't know if that's right. I'm also not entirely sure who would be the arbiter for "standard practice" in this situation.

Comment: Thank-you for your comment. Yes, a couple of articles I came across mentioned about storing in local storage too - but there were some comments saying that may not be a good idea... I like this company and want to make a good impression, so thought I would ask here too..

Comment: If you are talking about a token for a third-party API, you can't keep that securely in your user's browser. You need to keep that token on your server, and write your own endpoint to make calls to the third-party service. You can only entrust a user with a token that authenticates *them* to *your* service, not one that authenticates *you* to another service. If you are talking about the user's JWT, then I recommend a secure, httpOnly cookie, together with protection against XSRF.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do, I use a custom implementation of [**HttpInterceptor**](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor), this way, every HTTP Request will have the token, if there is one, if not, the request will continue normally.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
//Service where I handle the token
import { UserSettings } from "./user.settings";

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{

    constructor(private userSettings: UserSettings){}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) : Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
        //Check if the user is authenticated, if true, append the token   
        if(this.userSettings.isAuthenticated()){
            //Get the token
            let token: string = this.userSettings.getSessionToken();
            //Clone the original request (to be able to modify it)
            let clonedReq: HttpRequest<any> = req.clone({
                setHeaders: {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + token }
            });
            //Return the cloned request with the token
            return next.handle(clonedReq);
        }
        //At this point, the user is not authenticated, so I send the original request
        else{
            return next.handle(req);
        }        
    }
}
```

And in the providers array of the module:

```
providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true, },
],
```

For storing the token, at this moment I use LocalStorage, but I've read a couple of blog post about not doing it that way primarily for security reasons:

> Any JavaScript code on your page can access local storage: it has no data protection whatsoever. [This is the big one for security reasons. That is pretty bad.](https://medium.com/@saivicky2015/why-jwt-shouldnt-be-stored-in-local-storage-aa9aeacc46a0)